# Tika zip bomb exception

Tags: java, solr, sax, apache-tika

We are using Tika 1.1 to extract content from an XLSM file. We have two instances of our server. On one of the servers the file content is getting extracted properly. But on another server I am getting zip bomb exception for the same file. We are using same tika standalone jar at both instances. But I am not able to identify the issue.

Not sure whether the SAX configuration is creating a problem at runtime (I am not well versed with SAX). How can I debug this issue?

> Caused by: org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Zip bomb detected!
>           at org.apache.tika.sax.SecureContentHandler.throwIfCauseOf(SecureContentHandler.java:192)
>           at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:123)
>           at org.apache.tika.Tika.parseToString(Tika.java:380)
>           at com.ptc.search.solr.contentReader.contentExtraction.TikaExtractor.getContent(TikaExtractor.java:36)
>           ... 45 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.tika.sax.SecureContentHandler$SecureSAXException: Suspected zip bomb: 878 levels of XML element nesting
>           at org.apache.tika.sax.SecureContentHandler.startElement(SecureContentHandler.java:234)
>           at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.startElement(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:126)
>           at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.startElement(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:126)
>           at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.startElement(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:126)
>           at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.startElement(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:126)
>           at org.apache.tika.sax.SafeContentHandler.startElement(SafeContentHandler.java:264)
>           at org.apache.tika.sax.XHTMLContentHandler.startElement(XHTMLContentHandler.java:244)
>           at org.apache.tika.sax.XHTMLContentHandler.startElement(XHTMLContentHandler.java:274)
>           at org.apache.tika.sax.XHTMLContentHandler.element(XHTMLContentHandler.java:313)
>           at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.XSSFExcelExtractorDecorator.extractHeaderFooter(XSSFExcelExtractorDecorator.java:145)
>           at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.XSSFExcelExtractorDecorator.buildXHTML(XSSFExcelExtractorDecorator.java:129)
>           at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.AbstractOOXMLExtractor.getXHTML(AbstractOOXMLExtractor.java:104)
>           at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLExtractorFactory.parse(OOXMLExtractorFactory.java:110)
>           at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLParser.parse(OOXMLParser.java:82)
>           at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:242)
>           at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:242)
>           at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:120)
>           ... 47 more

Comment: "a "zip bomb", i.e. a compressed document that expands to excessive amounts of extracted text. "

Comment: yes, XLSM document is actually a zipped document. But my concern is content extraction of same file works well in one environment but not in another. And I am not able to find out the differences between the two environments. Is there anything I need to look for?

Comment: The default permitted XML nesting level is 100, if you exceed this you get that exception. A solution would be to increase the default maxPackageEntryDepth. The maximum nesting limits can be set directly on the SecureContentHandler level.

Comment: Tika 1.1 is rather old, is there a reason why you're not using the latest version? (1.5)

Comment: After debugging the tika code I realized that I had set maxStringLength on WriteOutContentHandler and the code was throwing zip bomb error after the limit is reached. Correct error message might have helped sooner. Anyway, thanks all for the input. We will definitely plan to move to latest release.

Comment: Should we create a defect in Jira to throw proper error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging the tika code I realized that I had set maxStringLength on WriteOutContentHandler and the code was throwing zip bomb error after the limit is reached. Correct error message might have helped sooner. Anyway, thanks all for the input. We will definitely plan to move to latest release.

Should we create a defect in Jira to throw proper error message?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem installing

```
emerge app-office/unoconv
```

and executing

```
$ unoconv -fpdf file.xlsm
```

It will create a .pdf file in the same directory of the file, then you can send it to Tika.

*My server is Gentoo, then adapt to your dist.*